# AJAX JSON request shows as undefined by typeof

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, undefined

I am getting undefined error when trying to assign a value from my ajax retrieved local json file. I can alert and console.log the data just fine but I get an error when trying to assign a value to a variable. typeof returns "undefined".

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "fhtyhtfht",
        "website": "fthfthfth",
        "description": "trgrgfthyg",
        "type": "marker",
        "coordinates": [
            54.637465,
            -8.440456
        ]
    },
...
]
```

Json is retrieved with ajax and the returned variable is of type object. I am able to retrieve string values with data.name for example but coordinated is undefined.

```
console.log(typeof data.coordinates); // undefined
console.log(typeof data.coordinates[0]); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Edit: The issue frustratingly was caused because I defined a variable with the same name as the method property, coincidentally many properties existed in both variables so the issue only arose with one property.

Comment: `typeof config` , if you are trying to get property `typof` then use `config['typeof']`

Comment: ^ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: I was indeed using the typeof incorrectly. I did eventually found the issue further down the stream, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
console.log(typeof config == "undefined")
```

or even

```
try {
    console.log(config)
} catch(e){
    console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: I am getting "true" from typeof config == "undefined" which if I am not mistaken means it IS in fact undefined.

Comment: True that. You need to parse the JSON object first before attaching a property though.

Comment: dataType is set to json, why do I need to parse it?

Comment: Link to an example please, since I have never seen eaxmples of or needed to parse json if dataType is defined correctly.